# What happened when c++ program getting a runtime error?

Tags: exception, operating-system, compiler-warnings

Say, in C++, if dereferencing a pointer that pointing to a memory that already released, I will get a bad access message and back to OS. Can someone explain what happened there a little bit in detail? It is an interview question on OS/compiler.

Comment: I believe that the OS has knowledge of the memory segments that you are allowed to access/use and when you free something you remove it from that list. So trying to access that memory results in the os not allowing you to use it(I.E. a segmentation fault). This is a safety feature and also helps to prevent silent failures in programs

Answer (score 0):

Once you **`delete`** that memory however, C++ marks it as free and may hand it out to anyone that asks for it.

Because deleting a block of memory **`does not zero the value of all pointers`** that point to it. Deleting memory merely makes a note that the memory is available to be allocated for some other purpose. Until that happens, the **`memory may appear to be intact`** -- but you can't count on it, and on some compiler/runtime/architecture combinations, your **`program will behave differently`** -- it may even crash.

Comment: crash is the best possible outcome of UB. it may even work and only crash when presenting the software to your clients

Comment: @Bryan Chen: Yes exactly. Most time it crashes but some time it may not crash also in case of dangling pointers.